# wpf mvvm - Is there a way to programmatically create textbox based on number of properties in model and bind to each of them in?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have multiple objects with multiple properties which I want to display or hide (or create if needed) based on the property value.

For example:
Model:

```
     public class InputModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool Required { get; set; }
    public int Dpi { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public List<ColorModel> Filter { get; set; }
    public List<RenderModel> Render { get; set; }
    public List<LayoutModel> Layout { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
      <ItemsControl x:Name="InputsList"
                  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="400">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Beige" Margin="10">
                            
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat='Name: {0}'}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id, StringFormat='Id: {0}'}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type, StringFormat='Type: {0}'}"/>
                        <CheckBox Grid.Column="1" Content="Required" Margin="0,5,0,0"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=Required, Path=CheckBoxIsChecked}"/>
                            <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4"
                                   Text="{Binding Dpi, StringFormat='Dpi: {0}'}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5"
                                   Text="Render:"/>
                            
                    </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

And my ViewModel:

```
public class InputsListViewModel : Screen
{
    private IRootModel _rootModel;

    public InputsListViewModel(IRootModel rootModel)
    {
        _rootModel = rootModel;
    }

    private BindingList<InputModel> _inputs;

    public BindingList<InputModel> InputsList
    {
        get
        {
            _inputs = new (_rootModel.Inputs);
            return _inputs;
        }
        set
        {
            _inputs = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => InputsList);
        }
    }

    private BindingList<RenderModel> _renders;

    public BindingList<RenderModel> RenderList
    {
        get 
        {
            _renders = new(_rootModel.Render);
            return _renders;
        }
        set 
        {
            _renders = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => RenderList);
        }
    }

    private BindingList<LayoutModel> _layouts;

    public BindingList<LayoutModel> LayoutList
    {
        get
        {
            _layouts = new (_rootModel.Layout);
            return _layouts;
        }
        set
        {
            _layouts = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => LayoutList);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't need to display all of the properties in here, just the ones that I need at a given time. And I want to be able to add any of the properties that are missing, if I need to.

I am a beginner and so far I only know how to manually create the fields that I need in view and bind to them.

Thanks!

Comment: You can control the visibility of the each item (property) via a boolean property or you can create a converter and if it has value then show the visible to true else false. But, I prefer the first option. This is the good and right way to solve your question. Hope it helps you to proceed further.

Comment: What objects or properties do you want to show/hide and when?

Comment: @mm8 - Any property when it's null or it's value is 0.

Comment: @G K - tried that, it works only on objects with a single property where I can use a simple ListBox for display, not ItemsControl. Or (and that's a strong possibility) I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can hide whole items with ItemContainerStyle or individual Properties as shown in 2 different ways

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding ShowInUi, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat='Name: {0}'}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id, StringFormat='Id: {0}'}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type, StringFormat='Type: {0}'}"/>
                    
                <!--possibility 1-->
                <TextBlock x:Name="AdditionalInfoText" Text="{Binding AdditionalInfo}"/>
                <!--possibility 2-->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SuperDuperValue}" Visibility="{Binding IsSuperDuperItem, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>

            </StackPanel>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AdditionalInfo}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter TargetName="AdditionalInfoText" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

For all textblocks in an area

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text.Length, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Second solution works, but is there a way to apply this to all texblocks (I have a lot of them, this is just a small, sample part) at once and also, I need to collapse the TexBlock either on null or 0 values.